# AngularJs - How should I detach a modal window?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

So I've been working with AngularJS for a decent amount of time, yet still have to understand the scenes behind directives.

I am trying to build a directive which attaches a modal window on demand and detaches it from the DOM if not needed anymore.

So i did this:

```
    app.directive('myDirective',function($document){

    return{

        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'partials/modules/template.html',
        link: function($scope,$element){

            var body = $document.find('body').eq(0);

            $element.remove();            

            $scope.create = function(){                 
               body.append($element);                   
            };

        }

    }

});
```

And found that it will cause the loss of linking between view and controller.

So far, so bad.

But what basic concept am i missing here? What would be a proper way to accomplish this?

I've got a few, messy (and hacky) options in my head, including

- using `ng-show`
- setting a CSS class of `hide` manually
- Re-linking the stuff back together after append

They seem weird and simply wrong to me, and i especially don't want to use a style attribute to do this.

I also don't want to use Angular-UI's modal module.

Comment: Can you create a demo plunker of fiddle for us to play with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should definitely re-consider your view about using a style attribute. It is the angular recommended way to go:

'*One of the major design goals of AngularJS is to allow application developers to build web apps with little or no direct manipulation of the DOM. In many cases this also leads to a much more declarative style of programming. This allows business logic to be easily unit tested and greatly increases the rate at which you can develop applications.*' [What is the AngularJS way to show or hide a form element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13288136/what-is-the-angularjs-way-to-show-or-hide-a-form-element)

I do this kind of thing all the time. Using ng-class and json, it is in my view the simplest way of doing it and the easiest way to test. Here's a rough idea. Also you don't need to append the element to the body, that is the whole purpose of the link phase:

```
app.directive('myDirective',function($document){

return{

   restrict: 'E',
   templateUrl: '<div myDirective ng-class="{\'hideClass\':object.hide===true, \'showClass\':object.show===true "></div>',
   link: function($scope,$element){

      scope.element= {hide:false, show:true}          

      if(someCondition) {
         scope.element.hide = true;
      }
      if (anotherCondition) {
         scope.element.show = true;
      } 

    }

  }

});
```

Then, in your test:

```
it('should be hidden if...', function () {
   angular.mock.inject(function ($compile, $rootScope) {
      var scope = $rootScope.$new();
      var elem = $compile('<div myDirective></div>')(scope);
      // ... some conditional code to manipulate scope.element json, you may need timeout to wait for DOM to load so you can check that the class is present            
      expect(elem.hasClass('hideClass')).toBe(true);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is when you call $element.remove() and then body.append($element) in the create method, it is no longer "compiled" angular. This is why the linking is broken. Compiling and appending everytime you want to show isn't the most efficient solution (as you mention above).

Why is it considered hacky to use CSS for display and hiding of the element/modal? This is how I've seen it done in most UI frameworks.

I've put together a jsfiddle of what I believe your [problem is](http://jsfiddle.net/pPtw7) (button in template can't call hideMe function) and an example using [CSS class](http://jsfiddle.net/pPtw7/1/).

Ignoring the simplicity of the styles:

```
.modal.show {
    display: block;
}

.modal {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    margin: 15px auto auto;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    padding: 5px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: white;
    z-index: 200;
}
```

Use addClass and removeClass within your scope methods for creating/hiding the modal:

```
mod.directive("myDirective", function () {
    return{

        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        template: '<div class="modal">Hello<button ng-click="hideMe()">&times;</button></div>',
        link: function($scope,$element){
            var shade = angular.element('<div class="shade"></div>');    

            $scope.create = function(){                 
               $element.addClass("show");                   
               $element.after(shade);
            };

            $scope.hideMe = function () {
                $element.removeClass("show");
                shade.remove();
            }

        }
    }
});
```

Hiding/showing elements is one of the thing CSS does really well. You can also get some nice animations and transitions if you wanted using CSS with minimal extra work.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. I've implemented the directive using ng-show now.

However, i explicitly didn't want to do so because i wanted to learn how it's done otherwise :) After some rethinking, i came to the conclusion that I'm good to go with this solution. Nevertheless, i am missing the expertise

Comment: The framework gives you at least 3 options for doing it that you mention above. Don't use a hammer to do a screwdriver's job :)... But as far as your question goes if you wanted to remove the element from the DOM, you must use $compile when adding it back in. But as you notice, that is unnecessary and there are better ways to do it (through ng-show and CSS class for instance).

Comment: This solution is fine but you are still manipulating the DOM by using addClass() and removeClass(). If you use ng-class in the original template with conditions that resolve according to the state of some json object then angular does all the work for you.

Comment: I already gave your answer an upvote :) I think we both agree that CSS is the way to go though.